# Why does this code report an error: "AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'connection_made' "

Tags: python

THe following code is for listening HTTP request on port 9000,and get response, but it doesn't work,report error " AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'connection_made'  ",don't understand why.

```
import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

import asyncio, os, json, time
from datetime import datetime

from aiohttp import web

def index(request):
    return web.Response(body=b'<h1>Awesome</h1>')

async def init(loop):
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', index)
    srv = await loop.create_server(app(), '127.0.0.1', 9000)
    logging.info('server started at http://127.0.0.1:9000...')
    return srv

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

The full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 829, in loop
    self._make_socket_transport(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 636, in _make_socket_transport
    return _ProactorSocketTransport(self, sock, protocol, waiter,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 602, in __init__
    super().__init__(loop, sock, protocol, waiter, extra, server)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(loop, sock, protocol, waiter, extra, server)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 328, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 66, in __init__
    self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.connection_made, self)
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'connection_made'
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the _full_ stack trace of the error?

Comment: `srv = await loop.create_server(app, '127.0.0.1', 9000)` ... ?

Comment: `srv = await loop.create_server(app, '127.0.0.1', 9000)` still don't work

Answer (score 1):

i think you should create server with web.AppRunner:

```py
app_runner = web.AppRunner(app)
await app_runner.setup() 
srv = await loop.create_server(app_runner.server, '127.0.0.1', 9000)
```